# struts to spring migration message resources

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web-applications, struts

I am converting an application from struts 1 to Spring MVC and I am trying to figure out what to do in my Java code when its using the import org.apache.struts.config.MessageResourcesConfig and org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources. In the spring-servlet.xml file I added the line to include my message resources properties file but I am not longer going to use the struts 1 libraries. How would I go about the conversion of this part of the code?

It is used a good bit throughout the application such as places like this:

```
this.config = new MessageResourcesConfig();
 this.config.setParameter("path that was used here was set in the spring-servlet configuration file");
 this.resources = MessageResources.getMessageResources(this.config.getParameter());
```

Comment: I still have not been able to figure this out so if anyone has any insight into this please let me know.

Comment: Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Comment: Still not sure what to do about this, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would refactored the way you load the Resources using `java.util.ResourceBundle`

```
// load resourcebundle.properties
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resourcebundle");
```

You can then get a value using

```
String val = bundle.getString(key);
```

You can have an helper class to get the values you need, and/or find a way to pass it to the JSP (cannot help you there, sorry)